# Uploading large files to webserver

Tags: bash, curl

I have to upload a lot of files to a nexus repository. Combined the files are around 60GB. What I'm doing right now is the following:

1. Download ZIP file from Jfrog artifactory
2. Unzip ZIP file
3. Loop through every file and upload to the nexus repository using curl

This is all done in a simple bash script.
This works but takes a long time. Can I somehow do this another way that is faster? Or are there a better solution to this problem? I'm open for all suggestions.

Comment: some reason not to unzip after the transfer?

Comment: The nexus repository does not support unzipping.

Comment: Does your end-to-end infrastructure support a "high" rate of transfer? you can run `N` file-transfer commands in the background from each other, but this assumes all elements can support high throughput. At least local-disk, local-network, CPU with multiple sftp clients running, the WAN connection, probably other elements, and the receiving end similar. OR at least let that be your model and scale to as many backgrounded tasks that produce positive results. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can try uploading all files in a single request (if there are not *too* many files):

```bash
curl -F file=@file1 -F file=@file2 $repository_url
```

This will eliminate the overhead of sending multiple HTTP requests. However, not much can be done if the bottleneck is bandwidth since those 60GB of data must somehow be transferred to the remote server.